# python global import to all files of a project

Tags: python

I have a file of types (let's call it `types.py`) that I use in almost all files of my "not so small" project.

I would like to avoid importing it to all of them. I was wondering if there is a way to make it global to the project.

Comment: No, there is no way. This would be a bad idea anyway

Comment: So you want something that works like pytest fixtures that are defined in conftest.py and magically works in all test files without explicit import?

Comment: @mx0 yep, unless there is a good reason not do to that.